# set font for text view android (from font file)

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a font file love.ttf (5mb). i had put it into assets folder.
This is my code

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"love.ttf");;
    tv.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.NORMAL);
    tv.setTextSize(20);
}
```

main.xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#4B67A1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="おはようございます。" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

when i run it, i can't see the text!!!
how to load a large font?
please help me!
thanks

Comment: It seems that problem should be for ttf file.

Comment: Did you solve that problem? I'm running into the issue that this actually works on Android 2.3+, but not on <2.2.

Answer (score 2):

So, there will be firstly two possible reason why it doesn't work.

1. Check if your font supports Japanese characters.
2. You could have bad path of your font file.

   ```
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/love.ttf");
   ```

You should have in your `assets` folder next subfolder named `fonts`. Then also check if you have correct suffix of font.

Comment: this is a font http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-+%E3%82%89%E3%81%B6+S2G+Love

I have change 
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/love.ttf");

but it still...

Comment: have you added your font into assets/fonts folder? if it still doesn't work your font not supports japanese characters, change font.im not pro in fonts but this font seems that not support your desired characters.

Comment: yes, i had added font into assets/folder, this is a japanese font, but, i can see the text. the font file size is 5mb, i think font file is large

Comment: i had upload project at here : https://skydrive.live.com/?lc=1066#cid=264D43810E6C110C&id=264D43810E6C110C!1192 can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to not directly save font in Asset folder,rather create fonts folder under it and inside that save love.ttf font.

Then you can perform the magic as below.

```
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/love.ttf"); 
  tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: this is font http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-+%E3%82%89%E3%81%B6+S2G+Love

i think font file is large! size : 5mb

Comment: android 2.2? i wrote in android 2.2, but i can see the text, what is text you've shown?